# Kafka cluster & Inter Data centre network latency relationship

Tags: networking, apache-kafka, latency

In my company we are running a kafka cluster currently **across** 3 AZs in a single region on AWS. There are multiple Topics with many partitions and their replicas. We know Amazon does not provide offical stats for inter AZ latency but when we test it is really v. fast or rather extremely low latency & about sub millisecond (1ms). We have producers and consumers also in the same AWS region within those same AZs.

To save on operational costs, I am currently investigating impact if we move this entire Kafka cluster & producers and consumers back on-prem and create a similar cluster across 3 DCs.

I am asking this question because - The inter DC latency in the company is E2E roughly 10ms oneway...so What would be the impact if this inter DC latency increases 10fold from say 1MS t0 10MS.

I am asking this because apart from the producers, consumers, even brokers also communicate with each other across DC (e.g. replicas are reading the messages from leaders, controller is informing other brokers about changes), some changes written as metadata to a zookeeper. What are the pitfalls that I should watch out for ?

Sorry for such an open question but want to know if anyone have experience and want to share issues, pitfalls etc. How does the Kafka broker and zookeeper get impacted if a cluster spans across a DC when latency is higher compared to AWS AZ latency. Is it even practical ?

Comment: Almost all companies that run Kafka in AWS (including Confluent Cloud or MSK) use multiple AZs... They just happen to adjust the connection timeouts to accommodate for the latencies

Comment: Yes, true but those multi AZs usually have super fast bandwidth to respond in 1ms or less. My question was what would be the impact if those latencies increased 10times e.g. 10MS or higher. What is the impact to the cluster performance if the cluster spans data centres ? For e.g. ZooKeeper is sensitive to latency between sites, which can cause big problems